# List all the cyclic subgroups of $\langle\mathbb Z_{10}, +\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to get the hang of it, so my work is very belabored. Please, see if any of that is correct.

Counterexamples:

$\mathbb Z_2 = \{0, 1\}$ is not subgroup since $1 + 1 = 2$ is outside $\mathbb Z_2.$

$\mathbb Z_3 = \{0, 1, 2\}$ is not a subgroup since $3 + 1 = 4$ is outside $\mathbb Z_5.$

$\mathbb Z_4 = \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$ is not a subgroup since $3 + 1 = 4$ is outside $\mathbb Z_4.$

$\mathbb Z_5 = \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}$ is not a subgroup since $4 + 1 = 5$ is outside $\mathbb Z_3.$

$\mathbb Z_6 = \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ is not a subgroup since $5 + 1 = 6$ is outside $\mathbb Z_6.$

$\mathbb Z_7 = \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ is not a subgroup since $6 + 2 = 8$ is outside $\mathbb Z_7.$

$\mathbb Z_8 = \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7\}$ is not a subgroup since $5 + 3 = 8$ is outside $\mathbb Z_8.$

$\mathbb Z_9 = \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8\}$ is not a subgroup since $7 + 2 = 9$ is outside $\mathbb Z_9.$

---

$\mathbb Z_1 = \{0\}$.

$0 + 0 = 0$, so $0 \in \mathbb Z_1$ and $0$ is the identity and its own inverse, so $\mathbb Z_1$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_1$.

$\mathbb Z_{10} = \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\}$

Let $c \neq 0 \in \mathbb Z_{10}.$ Then $c + 0 = c, \forall c \in \mathbb Z_{10}.$ So, $0$ is the identity. $c + d = 0 \to d = -c,$ so $-c$ is the inverse. The sum of any two elements in $Z_{10}$ is still in $Z_{10}.$ So $\mathbb Z_{10}$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_{10}$.

Comment: In general, you'll have more counterexamples than examples, and it is generally not sensible to list the counterexamples.  Also, what about $\{0,5\}$?

Comment: @ Omnomnomnom I am not sure, but I think $\{0, 5\}$ is not cyclic.

Comment: What makes you think so?

Comment: What is your definition of a cyclic (sub)group?

Comment: Indeed, as Omnomnomnom points out, there are infact $2^{10}=1024$ *subsets* of $\{0,1,\dots,9\}$  You have listed only 10 of the 1024 possible.  However, noting that in the context of $(\mathbb{Z}_4,+)$ you have $3+1=4=0\in\mathbb{Z}_4$, so your arguments for why they are nonexamples is invalid.  Infact, $\mathbb{Z}_4$ *is* a group (although not a *subgroup* of $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$).

Comment: @ Omnomnomnom, I just looked up "cyclic": $\{0, 5\}$ is cyclic because both $0$ and $5$ are in $\{0, 5\}.$ Here $\{0, 5\}$ must contain all the sums of its elements to be cyclic and it does.

Comment: @algebra That is not communicating what _cyclic_ means. The set is _cyclic_ if there is some one element in it, such that if you took all whole number multiples of that one element, you have your set back. In your example, $\{0,5\}$ is cylclic (all viewed in $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$) because it is the same as $\{\ldots,-5,0,5,10,\ldots\}$.

Comment: This is chapter 5, set E, exercise 1 in *Pinter*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cyclic subgroups are those generated by a single element. Let's look at $H = \langle 2 \rangle$ as an example. This means the subgroup generated by $2$. So, we start off with $2$ in $H$, then do the only thing we can: add $2 + 2 = 4$. So, just by having $2$, we were able to reach $4$. Now we know that $2$ and $4$ are both in $H$. We already added $2 + 2$, so let's try $2 + 4 = 6$. Now we know $6$ is in $H$ as well. Next would come $6 + 2 = 8$, then finally $8 + 2 = 10 \equiv 0 \mod 10$. Now if we try $0 + 2 = 2$, we've landed back at something we started with, $2$. Thus we say that $\langle 2 \rangle = \{0,2,4,6,8\}$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$, and it's cyclic because it's generated by a single element, in this case $2$.

I think you've chosen a bad direction to find these - for example, I see $\{0, 1, 2\}$ listed, but you know that $\mathbb{Z}_{10} = \langle 1 \rangle$, so any subgroup containing $1$ must necessarily be the whole group.

Since cyclic subgroups are those generated by a single element, why not pick each element of $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ and see what subgroup it generates, by adding that element to itself until you get back to where you started? For example, $\langle 2 \rangle = \{0, 2, 4, 6, 8\}$.

Comment: @ pjs36, Can you elaborate about $\mathbb Z_{10} = <1>?$ I don't know how that works.

Comment: @algebra in general, for $(G,+)$ and some $a\in G$, the subgroup generated by $a$, denoted as $\left< a\right>$ is the set $\{\dots,-a-a,-a,0,a,a+a,a+a+a,a+\dots+a,\dots\}$ or more conveniently written as $\{k\cdot a~:~k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$.  In particular, $\mathbb{Z}_{10}=\{0,1,1+1,1+1+1,\dots,1+\cdots+1\}=\{0,1,\dots,9\}$

Comment: @algebra I've added an explanation at the beginning.

Comment: @ pjs36 $3 + 3 = 6, 6 + 3 = 9, 9 + 3 = 2, 2 + 3 = 5, 5 + 3 = 8, 8 + 3 = 2$, so $<3> = \{0, 3, 6, 9, 2, 5, 8\}.$ Is that correct?

Comment: @algebra Ah, but $8 + 3 \equiv 1$, so there are a few more you get. You're definitely on the right track now though!

Comment: @ pjs so first we list all $<n> \in Z_{n}$, then apply the subgroup test to every $<n>$. After that we list the sets that pass the subgroup test, correct?

Comment: @algebra Yeah, that's a good strategy. I don't know how much group theory you know, but if you successfully compute $\langle a \rangle$ for any $a \in \mathbb{Z}_{10}$, it's guaranteed to be a subgroup. However, it wouldn't hurt to use the subgroup test to make sure everything checks out. P.S., don't forget $\langle 0 \rangle$.

Answer (score 7):

Your attempt can't be successful. Since any subgroup must contain $0$, you have to consider all subsets of $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ that contain $0$ and there are $2^9=512$ of them.

You have a *basic* information: you want to list all *cyclic* subgroups, so they *must* have a generator by assumption. Hence you just consider
$$
\langle 0\rangle=\{0\}\\
\langle 1\rangle=\mathbb{Z}_{10}\\
\langle 2\rangle=\{0,2,4,6,8\}\\
\langle 3\rangle=\{0,3,6,9,2,5,8,1,4,7\}=\mathbb{Z}_{10}\\
\dots
$$
(just start from one element, put in $0$, then keep adding the chosen element until you get back to $0$).

You'll discover that there are just four cyclic subgroups. Indeed, a basic theorem on groups tells you that the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ are in one to one correspondence with the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$ containing $10\mathbb{Z}$, so $10\mathbb{Z}$, $2\mathbb{Z}$, $5\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Z}$. And, since these are cyclic, also their images in $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ are cyclic.

Another important thing to note: $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is ***not*** a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_m$ if $m\ne n$.

Comment: +1 Also you don't really need to explicitly "put in" $0$, since the generator will get there.

Comment: @alex.jordan Yes, but I prefer starting the recursion from $0$ as a general rule.

Comment: @egreg This may be a dumb question but, you say at the end $Z_n$ is not a subgroup of $Z_m$ if $n\neq m$, but consider your example, $\langle 2 \rangle$ is a cyclic group of order 5, hence isomorphic to $Z_5$ no?

Comment: @Jimmy2Goons Isomorphic doesn't mean equal.

Answer (score 1):

The subgroups of $\Bbb Z$ are of the form $n\Bbb Z$, $n \in \Bbb Z$. Further, $m\Bbb Z \supseteq n\Bbb Z$ if and only if $m | n$. Now, the subgroups of $\Bbb Z_{10}$ correspond to the subgroups of $\Bbb Z$ which contain $10\Bbb Z$. The subgroups of $\Bbb Z$ which contain $10 \Bbb Z$ are $\Bbb Z$, $2\Bbb Z$, $5\Bbb Z$, and $10 \Bbb Z$. The corresponding subgroups of $\Bbb Z_{10}$ are respectively $\Bbb Z_{10}$, $2\Bbb Z_{10}$, $5\Bbb Z_{10}$, and $\{0\}$.

Comment: @ kobe, can you please define $2 \mathbb Z$ and $ 2\mathbb Z_{10}$, for example, more explicitly?

Comment: @algebra for $n$ an integer, $n\Bbb Z := \{nk : k\in \Bbb Z\}$ and $n\Bbb Z_{10} := \{nk : k\in \Bbb Z_{10}\}$.